# Exception with FormatXMLData

Tags: xml, delphi, svg, delphi-11-alexandria

I have this SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 67 67" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;"><g id="icon"><path d="M64.583,8.333c0,-3.449 -2.8,-6.25 -6.25,-6.25l-50,0c-3.449,0 -6.25,2.801 -6.25,6.25l0,50c0,3.45 2.801,6.25 6.25,6.25l50,0c3.45,0 6.25,-2.8 6.25,-6.25l0,-50Z" style="fill:#ebebeb;fill-opacity:0;stroke:#0dcaf2;stroke-width:4.01px;"/><g><circle cx="46.657" cy="16.816" r="8.809" style="fill:#f3ca69;"/><path d="M59.761,54.246l-15.758,-21.165c-0.508,-0.683 -1.548,-0.681 -2.054,0.003l-7.002,9.485l-11.004,-14.732c-0.506,-0.679 -1.525,-0.679 -2.032,-0l-14.753,19.758c-0.163,0.219 -0.253,0.485 -0.253,0.758l0,10.307l52.856,0l0,-4.414Z" style="fill:#4ea17e;fill-rule:nonzero;"/></g></g></svg>
```

In Delphi 11.3, when I load this file with the following code and try to format it with `FormatXMLData`, I get an exception:

```
var ThisXMLDoc := Xml.XMLDoc.TXmlDocument.Create(nil);
try
  ThisXMLDoc.LoadFromFile(EditSVGPath.Text);
  var FormattedSVGText := Xml.XMLDoc.FormatXMLData(ThisXMLDoc.XML.Text); // ExceptionMessage="Invalid node type", ExceptionName="EXMLDocError"
finally
  ThisXMLDoc.Free;
end;
```

How can I fix this error and properly format the XML?

UPDATE: The error occurs in `Xml.XMLDoc.pas` in `function CloneNodeToDoc` where `SourceNode.nodeType` is evaluated: If `SourceNode.nodeType = ntElement or ntAttribute or ntText, ntCData, ntComment or ntEntityRef or ntProcessingInstr or ntDocFragment` then SourceNode.nodeType is valid, else an exception is raised. This function is called by `function FormatXMLData` in Xml.XMLDoc.pas where the SourceNode parameter is passed as `(TXMLNode($A150E48) as IXMLNode)`.
(BTW, the SVG file was exported by Affinity Designer).

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086951/how-to-detect-node-type-error-in-svg-xml-and-possibly-fix-it Have you tried to remove the DTD?

Comment: It is undoubtedly related (not duplicate). I tried to remove the DTD, and the error still occurs. Please read the question update and try it for yourself. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried your code, and indeed it fails. However, when I remove the DTD, it *does* work.

Comment: Thank you for trying out. I am now working with a particular SVG library from Bruno Verhue, which, IMO is one of the best general SVG libraries. It offers SVG controls and methods that also solve this particular XML problem. Thanks to Bruno Verhue for his profound SVG knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce the issue, I created a new VCL application in Delphi 10.4 (Windows 7, 64-bit) with the following code:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Xml.XmlDoc;

{$R *.dfm}

const
  S =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' +
    '<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">' +
    '<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 67 67" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" '+'style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;">' +
    '<g id="icon">' +
    '<path d="M64.583,8.333c0,-3.449 -2.8,-6.25 -6.25,-6.25l-50,0c-3.449,0 -6.25,2.801 -6.25,6.25l0,50c0,3.45 2.801,6.25 6.25,6.25l50,0c3.45,0 6.25,-2.8 6.25,-6.25l0,-50Z" style="fill:#ebebeb;fill-opacity:0;stroke:#0dcaf2;stroke-width:4.01px;"/>' +
    '<g>' +
    '<circle cx="46.657" cy="16.816" r="8.809" style="fill:#f3ca69;"/>' +
    '<path d="M59.761,54.246l-15.758,-21.165c-0.508,-0.683 -1.548,-0.681 -2.054,0.003l-7.002,9.485l-11.004,-14.732c-0.506,-0.679 -1.525,-0.679 -2.032,-0l-14.753,19.758c-0.163,0.219 -0.253,0.485 -0.253,0.758l0,'+'10.307l52.856,0l0,-4.414Z" style="fill:#4ea17e;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>' +
    '</g>' +
    '</g>' +
    '</svg>';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var ThisXMLDoc := Xml.XMLDoc.TXmlDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    ThisXMLDoc.LoadFromXML(S);
    var FormattedSVGText := Xml.XMLDoc.FormatXMLData(ThisXMLDoc.XML.Text);
    RichEdit1.Text := FormattedSVGText;
  finally
    ThisXMLDoc.Free;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Indeed it fails, but with with the exception `EDOMParseError`: *DTD är förbjudet.* ’DTD not allowed.’

If I remove the DTD,

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Xml.XmlDoc;

{$R *.dfm}

const
  S =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' +
//    '<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">' +
    '<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 67 67" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" '+'style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;">' +
    '<g id="icon">' +
    '<path d="M64.583,8.333c0,-3.449 -2.8,-6.25 -6.25,-6.25l-50,0c-3.449,0 -6.25,2.801 -6.25,6.25l0,50c0,3.45 2.801,6.25 6.25,6.25l50,0c3.45,0 6.25,-2.8 6.25,-6.25l0,-50Z" style="fill:#ebebeb;fill-opacity:0;stroke:#0dcaf2;stroke-width:4.01px;"/>' +
    '<g>' +
    '<circle cx="46.657" cy="16.816" r="8.809" style="fill:#f3ca69;"/>' +
    '<path d="M59.761,54.246l-15.758,-21.165c-0.508,-0.683 -1.548,-0.681 -2.054,0.003l-7.002,9.485l-11.004,-14.732c-0.506,-0.679 -1.525,-0.679 -2.032,-0l-14.753,19.758c-0.163,0.219 -0.253,0.485 -0.253,0.758l0,'+'10.307l52.856,0l0,-4.414Z" style="fill:#4ea17e;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>' +
    '</g>' +
    '</g>' +
    '</svg>';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var ThisXMLDoc := Xml.XMLDoc.TXmlDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    ThisXMLDoc.LoadFromXML(S);
    var FormattedSVGText := Xml.XMLDoc.FormatXMLData(ThisXMLDoc.XML.Text);
    RichEdit1.Text := FormattedSVGText;
  finally
    ThisXMLDoc.Free;
  end;

end;

end.
```

it does work as expected:

[image: Screenshot of form]

Hence, your problem seems to be related to circumstances not detailed in your question or to a Delphi 11.3 issue not present in Delphi 10.4. The obvious question is what the encoding of your XML file is. On my system, it works well with UTF-8 (both with and without BOM), but it fails with UTF-16/32 LE/BE (both with and without BOM). However, in this case, the error message does explicitly complain about the encoding.